# iOS 10 MSMessageTemplateLayout: Which audio format?

Tags: imessage, ios10

I am currently trying to build a iMessag app that should send a sound to another user. I set up a little user interface and calling this code to send it to the other user:

```
MSMessage *newMessage = [[MSMessage alloc]init];  
    [newMessage setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://my.app/kiss.m4a"]];  
    MSMessageTemplateLayout *layout = [[MSMessageTemplateLayout alloc] init];  
    layout.mediaFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"kiss" ofType:@"m4a"]];  
    layout.trailingCaption = @"Kiss";  

    newMessage.layout = layout;  
    [self.activeConversation insertMessage:newMessage localizedChangeDescription:nil completionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {  

    }];
```

It will then make a message with the trailing caption but no sound so far. I have tried several formats including mp3, m4a, aac and amr. None of them seem to work and I could not find any documentation. Is there any information which sound formats are supported?

Thanks,
Philip

Comment: That code isn't complete: `@"https://my.app/kiss.m4a  `

Answer (score -1):

use *insertAttachment: withAlternateFilename: completionHandler:completionHandler* to send audio

Comment: That does work, but that's not what I want to have since I want to have the interactive format

Comment: I'm still not seeing this fixed in the latest beta. You might want to follow this question on the dev forums, its generally a better place to find answers about iOS stuff that is still in beta. https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/144726#144726 This is NOT my questions by the way I'm not trying to promote, Im just also trying to use the interactive format as well, since I want to send Audio with a caption not just the wave image they give you automatically and the file name.